# How to enable click functionality of div in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I disabled the div by using following code

```
$("#menuDiv1").children().bind('click', function(){ 
     return false; 
});
```

menuDiv contains

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="home" href="#/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a class="forms" href="#/ViewLeads">Lead</a></li>
    <li><a class="forms"  href="#/ViewCases/0">Cases</a></li> 


</ul>
```

but now I want to enable it again. How can I do that?

And is there any other solution for the same in angular js?

Comment: You are using Angular, then try to achieve the result using anuglar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `unbind` to remove disable click event

```
 $("#menuDiv1").children().unbind('click');
```

To re enable click event use below code.

```
  function clickfunc(){
     // your code
  }

  $("#menuDiv1").children().bind('click',clickfunc);
```

**Second option**

you can use `off` to remove disable click event

```
$("#menuDiv1").children().off('click');
```

To re enable click event use below code.

```
  function clickfunc(){
     // your code
  }

  $("#menuDiv1").children().on('click',clickfunc);
```

**EDIT**   as discussed below code is avoid click event on  `a,button` tags.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjbwh39q/2/)

```
function clickfunc(event){
     if(event.target.nodeName === 'A' || event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON"){
      return false;
     }

      // your code
     alert("click")
}

$("#menuDiv1").children().on('click',clickfunc);
```

Comment: there are no. of buttons and href tags that perform the different task on click . But if I use bind with clickfunc then it will perform same task for all . How can I resume the default operation of buttons and <a hrf> tags.

Comment: @SunilGarg  you use of not() function like `.children().not('button')`

Comment: @SunilGarg  here is perfect example for what you want it avoid buttons and href click and return false  http://jsfiddle.net/cjbwh39q/1/

Comment: The code you provided is working perfectly fine. But I need to restore my previous functionality of my div buttons. Please check question again I provided my div data

Comment: @SunilGarg can't understand .. means i have provide you many option to avoid click event on specific element . also i cant see button in side your HTML .. can you explain in detail ?? when you disable click event and when you want to enable click event ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use unbind to disable and bind to enable again.

```
$("#menuDiv1").children().unbind('click');
```

To bind it again

```
$("#menuDiv1").children().bind('click', clickhander);
```

You better look to use jQuery.on and jQuery.off instead of bind and unbind.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you can use `ng-click` and `ng-disabled` in combination. For example:

```
<button ng-click="clicked()" ng-disabled="val">Click</button>
```

And in controller set the `val` to `true` or `false` to `enable/disable` click on the button.

```
$scope.val = true; //To disable button
```

EDIT:

For div you can do it like this:

```
 <div ng-click="val || clicked()" ng-disabled="val">Click</div>
```

Comment: ng-disabled is working fine with buttons. But when I use it with div nothing happens. I mean buttons or <a href > still work. Can we apply it on div or not ?

Comment: <div class="container" id="menuDiv1" ng-disabled="true"> . I used directly true for ng-disabled. Not working.

Comment: @SunilGarg then in the `ng-click` replace val with `true`. But I recommend you to use a variable for ng-disabled instead of tru so that you can modify it later.

Comment: I changed my div to <div ng-click="val || clicked()" ng-disabled="val" class="container" id="menuDiv1"> and in controller set val to true. but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

using **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**/**[off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** you can enable or disable click event

**Disable click**

```
$("#menuDiv1").children().off('click');
```

**Enable Click**

```
$("#menuDiv1").children().on('click', function(){ 

// do here work

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would either unbind previously bound click event handler, or prevent event conditionally:

```
$("#menuDiv1").children().bind('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('no-click')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Btw, it's better to use `e.stopPropagation();` explicitly to prevent child-to-parent event bubbling, rather than implicit `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new information in your question, the proper way to do this in AngularJS is to use the `$locationChangeStart` event.

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iWNP5r8SEZAOzjGWO3BC?p=preview)

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if ($rootScope.menuDeactivated) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

This is a very simplistic example of that sets a variable on the $rootScope, but you could instead run a function (helpful if you want to save form values or prompt the user before changing your route for example) or inject a service (such as if you want to check if a user is logged in), etc.